# Access a dictionary value (dictionary value is a list) in tkinter OptionMenu and store in variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have an OptionMenu in tkinter. The options in the menu are keys from a dictionary. The value of each key is a list that contains 4 items.

How do I use the selected menu option to assign the 4 items to separate variables?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

options = {'option 1' : ['list item 1' , 'list item 2' , 'list item 3' , 'list item 4'] , 'option 2' : ['list item w' , 'list item x' , 'list item y' , 'list item z']}

options = sorted(options)

var = StringVar(root)
var.set('Choose an option')

option = OptionMenu(root, var, *options)
option.pack()

selection = StringVar()

def changeOption(*args):
    newSelection = options[var.get()]
    selection.set(newSelection)

var.trace('w', changeOption)

variable1 = # if option 1 was selected from the menu then this variable would contain list item 1
variable2 = # if option 1 was selected from the menu then this variable would contain list item 2
variable3 = # if option 1 was selected from the menu then this variable would contain list item 3
variable4 = # if option 1 was selected from the menu then this variable would contain list item 4

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: show simple, working code in question - so everyone could test it and make example for you.

Comment: OK. Code added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it in function `change_option`, not in main part.

Main part only create windows/GUI and starts `mainloop()`. And then `mainloop()` controls everything - it executes function `change_option` when you change option in `OptionMenu`.

You can use your `var.get()` or first argument send by `command=` to get key and then you can get data from dictionary.

But you can't assign `sorted()` to `options` because `sorted()` returns only list of sorted keys and you loose access to oryginal dictionary.

```
keys = sorted(options)
```

Full code:

```
from tkinter import *

# --- functions ---

def change_option(*args):

    # selected element

    print('     args:', args)
    print('var.get():', var.get())

    # get list from dictionary `options`

    data = options[var.get()]
    data = options[args[0]]

    print('     data:', data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3])

    # if you really need in separated varaibles

    variable1 = data[0]
    variable2 = data[1]
    variable3 = data[2]
    variable4 = data[3]

    print('variables:', variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4)

    print('---')

# --- main ---

root = Tk()

options = {
    'option 1': ['list item 1', 'list item 2', 'list item 3', 'list item 4'],
    'option 2': ['list item w', 'list item x', 'list item y', 'list item z']
}

keys = sorted(options) # don't overwrite `options` - sorted() returns only keys from dictionary.

var = StringVar(root)
var.set('Choose an option')

option = OptionMenu(root, var, *keys, command=change_option)
option.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

results:

```
     args: ('option 1',)
var.get(): option 1
     data: list item 1 list item 2 list item 3 list item 4
variables: list item 1 list item 2 list item 3 list item 4
---
     args: ('option 2',)
var.get(): option 2
     data: list item w list item x list item y list item z
variables: list item w list item x list item y list item z
---
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `command` option of OptionMenu. That command executes everytime you choose an option from dropdown.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def change_vars(e):
    for i in range(len(options[var.get()])):
        vars[i].set(options[var.get()][i])

    #these two prints added for debugging purposes 
    #to see if we are getting and setting right values
    print(options[var.get()])    
    for item in vars:
        print(item.get())

options = {'option 1':['list item 1','list item 2','list item 3','list item 4'] , 'option 2':['list item w','list item x','list item y','list item z']}

var = StringVar(root)
var.set('Choose an option')

option = OptionMenu(root, var, *options, command=change_vars)
option.pack()
vars = [StringVar() for _ in range(len(options[0]))] #creates a list of 4 stringvars
root.mainloop()
```

In here, instead of hardcoding all variables, I created them in a loop and stored them in a list.