# Trying to get the option selected from OptionMenu to grab multiple dictionary values in a nested dictionary with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to be able to grab each of the values I have in my nested dictionary based on whichever value is chosen.

To make this more clear, here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

totexd = {'TA200': {'burstdiam': 3.00, 'rfreelift': 0.510, 'mass': 0.20},
          'TA300': {'burstdiam': 3.78, 'rfreelift': 0.560, 'mass': 0.30},
          'TA350': {'burstdiam': 4.12, 'rfreelift': 0.585, 'mass': 0.35},
          'TA450': {'burstdiam': 4.72, 'rfreelift': 0.635, 'mass': 0.45},
          'TA500': {'burstdiam': 4.99, 'rfreelift': 0.655, 'mass': 0.50},
          'TA600': {'burstdiam': 6.02, 'rfreelift': 0.870, 'mass': 0.60},
          'TA700': {'burstdiam': 6.53, 'rfreelift': 0.920, 'mass': 0.70},
          'TA800': {'burstdiam': 7.00, 'rfreelift': 0.970, 'mass': 0.80},
          'TA1000': {'burstdiam': 7.83, 'rfreelift': 1.06, 'mass': 1.00},
          'TA1200': {'burstdiam': 8.63, 'rfreelift': 1.19, 'mass': 1.20},
          'TA1500': {'burstdiam': 9.44, 'rfreelift': 1.28, 'mass': 1.50},
          'TA1800': {'burstdiam': 9.98, 'rfreelift': 1.35, 'mass': 1.80},
          'TA2000': {'burstdiam': 10.54, 'rfreelift': 1.48, 'mass': 2.00},
          'TA3000': {'burstdiam': 13.00, 'rfreelift': 1.67, 'mass': 3.00}}


balloon = Label(root, text="Balloon Model: ").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E)

balloonmodel = StringVar(root)
balloonmodel.set("TA350")

balloonentry = OptionMenu(root, balloonmodel, *totexd).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E)

def grabinfo(*totexd):
    burstdiam = totexd.get(balloonentry).get("burstdiam")
    rfreelift = totexd.get(balloonentry).get("rfreelift")
    balloonmass = totexd.get(balloonentry).get("mass")

button1 = Button(root, text="Click me", command=grabinfo)
button1.grid(row=5)

root.mainloop()
```

So let's say when the window pops up the user selects from the drop down menu "TA350". I then want the values for burstdiam, rfreelift, and mass to have their specific value assigned to the variable name (what I tried to do in grabinfo(*totexd)).

When I run this code I get the error:

```
    burstdiam = totexd.get(balloonentry).get("burstdiam")
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I've tried a couple of different ways as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886155/assigning-values-to-optionmenu-in-tkinter), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/6oo2or/loading_dictionary_keysvalues_into_tkinter/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577746/tkinter-optionmenu-displayoptions-and-assignment-values) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039666/access-a-dictionary-value-dictionary-value-is-a-list-in-tkinter-optionmenu-and),  and many more. I saw an answer somewhere about using .get twice to get the nested dictionary value, but that doesn't work either. I can't find anything that is what I'm trying to do. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user's choice is stored in the StringVar, not in the OptionMenu. Also, you need to nme your arguments something else, otherwise you overwrite your dictionary name. "args" is a popular choice. Try this:

```
def grabinfo(*args):
    burstdiam = totexd.get(balloonmodel.get()).get("burstdiam")
    rfreelift = totexd.get(balloonmodel.get()).get("rfreelift")
    balloonmass = totexd.get(balloonmodel.get()).get("mass")
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that StringVar was the one that is stored from the user input, that's super helpful. And I also didn't know that I was overwriting my dictionary. So how does *args work? Is that just a blank dictionary?

Comment: No, it's a tuple, which is why your error complained that the tuple has no get method. You don't need `*args`, but having it there means you can call this function with any number of positional arguments, which are then ignored. This is a popular thing to do so that you can call the function from a Button as you have it (a Button sends no arguments), or a Variable trace (which sends 3 arguments), or an event binding (which sends 1 argument), or some other source.